# multiprocessing Pool, run in different directory for each items in list

Tags: python, multiprocessing

i am using multiprocessing.Pool module in my code, I am using the pool.map() function to run the items in the list in parallel, I want to create a separate working directory for each items in the list when the pool.map function is executed. The list items contains models and they will be simulated in simulate function. Currently my code looks like this

```
     items=['BouncingBall.mo','HelloWorld.mo']
     from multiprocessing import Pool
     from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool                             
     pool = ThreadPool()
     pool.map(parallel,items)

     def simulate(lists):
         np='some directory path'
         os.chdir(np)
         model.simulate(lists)
```

The simulate function will simulate each model in the list and generate result files, I want to execute the items in the list in different directories, I tried with os.chdir(), It creates two directories but the results are stored in the one directory for both the models, How to execute the result files in two different directories.Is it possible to create different directories for each process and execute seperately

Answer (score 1):

This call:

```
os.chdir(np)
```

Affects all threads (and the main thread) since they all belong to the **same** process.

You should open the files written to using the full path rather than changing the directory globally.

If you'd use real processes this wouldn't happen since you'd have **different** processes after the implicit `fork` calls.

Your options are:

1. do this serially.
2. Use processes instead of threads
3. provide path to store results as parameter (if possible) and use it.

Seems like you'll have to pick 1 or 2.

Comment: So what you mean to use instead of os.chdir(), should i use for this os.chdir('C:/BouncingBall') and write the result files to that  directory

Comment: When you're writing a result you probably open a file using something like `open(file, 'w')`. You should be using `open(DIR+file, 'w')` where `DIR` is the specific directory for this result. Without knowing exactly what you're doing it's hard to tell you what you should be doing, but that's the spirit of things.

Comment: I will not be writing any result, when this function model.simualte(BouncingBall.mo) is called it will generate the result files from the simulator i am using, i will not be writing anything, I want that result files to be generated in the newly created directory

Comment: What does `model.simulate` do? What is in the `lists` argument?

Comment: Some simulating model, for example simulate(BouncingBall.mo), simulate(HelloWorld.mo) will do some simulations and generate result files, i want to store each of these result files in two different directories

Comment: so you're calling `chdir` after **each** call to `simulate`?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but since the execution is going parallel i don't know how to switch directories after each simulation, but the result files are generated in one newly created directory

Comment: See updated answer. If you don't have access to `simulate` - either do this serially (one after the other), or use processes.